# Mail randomly closes "open email windows"

Tags: mail.app, email

Running on the following:

- macOS Ventura 13.2.1
- Mail 16.0 (3731.400.51.1.1)
- MacBook Pro M1

The following screen clip illustrates my issue.

[image]

As part of my email workflow I have Mail's "Viewer" window open and a number of emails as in the lower window in the attached screen clip (I'll refer to the lower window as the *open email window*).

This *open email window* can include (i) emails to which I need to read or reply or (ii) drafts of replies in process.

My problem, Mail appears to randomly close this *open email window*, wrecking havoc with my workflow.  I lose immediate visibility to items I need to address and have to try to reestablish what I had open - always an imperfect solution.

This behavior very much undermines my ability to perform my job.

Of note, this has happened both when I have had individual emails open as well as when I have emails in tabs in an *open email window*.

Why does this happen?
Can I stop it from happening?
Can I recover an *open email window*?
Does a workaround exist?

Do I need to stop using mail and move to Microsoft Outlook?
I dread doing this.  I have serious concerns about Microsoft software.

Thoughts|guidance appreciated.

Comment: What are the circumstances when this happens? (Have you rebooted - or shut down - before it happens? Or maybe you have closed the lid? Or made it sleep?) Is this only happening when using Mail or does it also happen with other apps? Is your Mac or iCloud account managed or supervised by your organisation/school?

Comment: This is not an answer but- Have you tried using the flag system? There's different flag colors and you can sort your emails using this criteria.

Comment: @Thinkr - I use an external monitor with my MacBook.  I always have the lid closed.  The problem seems most likely to happen overnight, while the machine sleeps.  This only happens with Mail.  This is my personal machine, no organizational/school interference or access.

Comment: @Thinkr - I have used flags.  I don't find them particularly effective.  They get lost in the overall volume of email.  The system I used gives me immediate access to my essential workflow.  The problem - Apple makes the functionality I need and use available, but has not made it reliable (or perhaps more kindly, hasn't provided clear guidance to use it so it doesn't screw things up.)

Comment: Okay. I'm then thinking that it could be because it logs you out after some inactivity. Try disabling the setting. Go to **System Settings > Privacy & Security** and disable the "**Log out after [number] minutes of inactivity**"  option. You may need to press the lock icon to make changes. Then try putting you Mac to sleep to see if the issue persists, inform me of the result. :)

Comment: @Thinkr - I have (and have always had) "Log out automatically after inactivity" off.  Also, this doesn't happen every time the machine sleeps.  Just weird.

Comment: Oh, not every time? Hm. Have you managed to replicate the issue at least once (in the day)? By making it sleep for example? Just to be sure we're on the right track.

Comment: It sounds like you Mail App is crashing. This could be due to damaged messages in your local store.  Try creating another user account (only for testing) and add your Email accounts to that user. Don’t create local folders or anything like that. Use email for a while and see if the problem goes away

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have this setting switched on? It would prevent the system from saving and restoring the window over a reboot.

- Apple menu  > System Settings.
- Click Desktop & Dock in the sidebar.
- Scroll down on the right and turn on “Close windows when quitting an app.”

Comment: You maybe mean "turn ***off*** "close windows when quitting...."?

Comment: Already in the "off" position.